# Fundo com blur e div do meio sem

Tags: css

Tenho uma `section`, que ocupa toda a área da janela do navegador, e com uma imagem de fundo preenchendo toda a sua área. Dentro desta `section` tenho uma `div` centralizada e com uma outra imagem de fundo.

Gostaria de aplicar um efeito `blur` na `section` de modo a desfocar a imagem do fundo, porém, gostaria que a `div` dentro da `section` não fosse afetada pelo efeito. O problema é que ao aplicar o `blur` na `section`, a `div` dentro dela também é afetada. Como poderia aplicar o `blur` na section sem afetar a `div`?

**Código:**

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

section{
   position: relative;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   background: url(https://images2.alphacoders.com/728/728536.jpg);
   background-attachment: fixed;
   height: 100vh;
   filter: blur(5px);
}

#meio{
   filter: blur(0);
   background-image: url(https://wallpaperstudio10.com/static/wpdb/wallpapers/1920x1080/195173.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
   width: 600px;
   height: 600px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: blue;
   border-width: 20px;
   box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px red;
}
```

```html
<section>
   <div id="meio"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Quando for adicionar uma pergunta, especifique sua dúvida, não poste apenas o código...

Respondendo o que eu acredito ser a pergunta, quando você utiliza o atributo "blur", ele pega todos os elementos de dentro, e aplica sem que possa ser removido, portanto assim não funcionaria.

Existem duas soluções: A primeira (que eu acredito ser a mais fácil) é editar a imagem em algum editor e depois utilizar a imagem
A segunda é colocar a div por fora da section e utilizar o position absolute para sobrescrever a imagem de baixo. 
(#meio {position: absolute; margin: 5% 0 0 30%;}

Answer (score 1):

Quando vc coloca algum efeito no "pai" vc não consegue remove-lo do filho. Então se o pai tem `blur`, ou `opacity`, ou algum outro efeito desse tipo vc não consegue retira-lo do filho, o efeito vai incidir nos dois!

**Opção 1**

Para evitar o problema vc pode criar um elemento `::after` na sa section, e nela vc coloca o fundo com o `Blur`, assim vc evita colocar o `Blur` diretamente no pai, e sim em um *pseudo-elemento* dele.

Veja como fica:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: url(https://images2.alphacoders.com/728/728536.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(https://images2.alphacoders.com/728/728536.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  filter: blur(5px);
}

#meio {
  /* filter: blur(0); */
  background-image: url(https://wallpaperstudio10.com/static/wpdb/wallpapers/1920x1080/195173.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  border-width: 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="meio"></div>
</section>
```

---

**Opção 2**

Esse modelo que eu fiz foi tirando o elemento filho de dentro do pai, depois usando `position:absolut` e `transform:translate` eu fiz os alinhamento. Veja como ficou o resultado.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  /* position: relative; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: url(https://images2.alphacoders.com/728/728536.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  filter: blur(5px);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#meio {
  filter: blur(0);
  background-image: url(https://wallpaperstudio10.com/static/wpdb/wallpapers/1920x1080/195173.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  border-width: 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<div id="meio"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra opção seria colocar outra div-filho com posição absoluta e aplicar o fundo e o blur nessa div. Essa div teria a função de background da section.

Criar um pseudo `::after` como propôs a resposta do @Hugocsl me parece ser a melhor alternativa, porém, caso você queira em algum momento manipular esse elemento com JavaScript, você não conseguirá porque pseudo-elementos não são manipuláveis via JS, já uma div comum sim.

Então ficaria:

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

section{
   position: relative;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   height: 100vh;
}

#meio{
   background-image: url(https://wallpaperstudio10.com/static/wpdb/wallpapers/1920x1080/195173.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
   width: 600px;
   height: 600px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: blue;
   border-width: 20px;
   box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px red;
}

#fundo{
   filter: blur(5px);
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: url(https://images2.alphacoders.com/728/728536.jpg);
   background-attachment: fixed;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<section>
   <div id="fundo"></div>
   <div id="meio"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Sempre tem mais um jeito quando o assunto é css :D